# Recyclerview separator with custom padding

Tags: android, android-layout, android-recyclerview

How to add custom padding to horizontal separator used in RecyclerView?

This is my solution so far but padding is completely ignored:

```
import android.content.Context
import android.graphics.Rect
import android.view.View
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.DividerItemDecoration
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
import android.util.TypedValue


class CustomDecoration(val context: Context?, orientation: Int, private val padding: Float) : DividerItemDecoration(context, orientation) {

    override fun getItemOffsets(outRect: Rect, view: View, parent: RecyclerView, state: RecyclerView.State) {
        val position = parent.getChildAdapterPosition(view)


        outRect.right = dpToPx(padding)
        outRect.left = dpToPx(padding)

        // hide the divider for the last child
        if (position == parent.adapter!!.itemCount - 1) {
            outRect.setEmpty()
        } else {
            super.getItemOffsets(outRect, view, parent, state)
        }
    }

    fun dpToPx(dp: Float): Int{
        val metrics = context?.resources?.displayMetrics
        return TypedValue.applyDimension(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, dp, metrics).toInt()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because you are calling the  `super.getItemOffsets(outRect, view, parent, state)`

if you look at this method you will notice it reset all values

```
  public void getItemOffsets(@NonNull Rect outRect, int itemPosition, @NonNull RecyclerView parent) {
        outRect.set(0, 0, 0, 0);
    }
```

so adjust your code like this to make it work

```
override fun getItemOffsets(outRect: Rect, view: View, parent: RecyclerView, state: RecyclerView.State) {
                super.getItemOffsets(outRect, view, parent, state)

        val position = parent.getChildAdapterPosition(view)


        outRect.right = dpToPx(padding)
        outRect.left = dpToPx(padding)

        // hide the divider for the last child
        if (position == parent.adapter!!.itemCount - 1) {
            outRect.setEmpty()
        }
    }

    fun dpToPx(dp: Float): Int{
        val metrics = context?.resources?.displayMetrics
        return TypedValue.applyDimension(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, dp, metrics).toInt()
    }
```